# Rails and rendering nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example: can I render '/tags/:id/posts'?

If I try to render tag_posts_path(@tag) or some other ways, I get this or similar error:

```
Missing partial /tags/1/posts...
```

In my routes.rb I have this:

```
resources :tags do
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What exactly do you want to render?

Comment: I think it's obvious. In the view '/tags/1' I can simply render eg.'tags/new', but I can not find a way to render '/tags/1/edit' or '/tags/1/posts'. When I google for "rendering nested routes", many people is trying to solve this but nobody knows, so I've tried this forum. But with no luck

Comment: There wouldn't be 2 downvotes if it was. Anyway, it'd be wise if you posted your routes.rb file.

Comment: @PetrCézar no it's not obvious. You would have had more answers if you could post more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stucked a bit with thing like yours

I achieved rendering correct page

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @comment = @project.comments.build(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Chingon!"
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'projects/show'
    end
  end
```

My routes looks like:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Rails expecting you to render not path but some page(like 'new' or 'show')
I got trouble only with my ELSE where I'm rendering 'projects/show'. It seem to be not quite right template, coz it renders in raw, without any CSS but with errors I expect to appear. It's the only way for now that I can render error messages for empty comment.

I walk over that issue simply by bypassing default way to display errors and place it in simple flash like this:

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @comment = @project.comments.build(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "New comment here, bro"
        redirect_to @project
    else
        redirect_to @project
        flash[:error] = flash_error_message(@comment)
    end
end


def flash_error_message(arg)
    "The form contains #{arg.errors.count} error: #{arg.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"       
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, I think what you are looking for is something like this

```
resources :tags do
  resources :posts
end
```

You can see what kind of urls or routes this generates by typing in `rake routes`

I'm not really sure but, re-reading your question I think you mean rendering by saying

`render 'some nested route'`

The above routes I provided would allow you to do something like this...

`render tag_posts_path(@tag)` that will in term look for a index action since its the posts path.  Again, `rake routes` shows all this.

A quick search on google for nested routes would've led you to this.

[Nested Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve. But "render tag_posts_path(@tag)" gives me error "Missing partial /tags/1/posts ..." and many other ways and attempts gives me similar errors. I've already spent couple of days on google, thank you.

Comment: Can you please update your question with your entire error? It'd help us figure out what the problem is exactly. It seems you don't have the necessary view to render. update your question with your error output and your `rake routes` output as well if you want more help. We can't help you without specifics of your problem or more info.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem with the same routes.rb. Got any idea how to solve this? Indeed, render doesn't work, which would be the regular method to call to render errors etc. It does work with redirect_to but this is not what we want.